# GET http://localhost:5000/auth/me 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-redux

I am following a MERN tutorial and made a React site where it receive data like **name** and **email** of the logged in user and then theses data are shown.

*Here my back code:*

**routes/user.js:**

```
const express = require('express')

const userController = require('../controllers/user')
const route = express.Router()
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/auth')


route.post('/', userController.register)
route.post('/login', userController.login)
route.get('/isauth', checkAuth, userController.isAuthenticated)
route.post('/logout', checkAuth, userController.logout)
route.post('/me', checkAuth, userController.getMe)


module.exports = route
```

**controllers/user.js:**

```
module.exports = {
getMe: (req, res) => {
        const {sub} = req.user

        User.findOne({_id : sub}, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    message : 'User not found',
                    data : null
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message : 'User found',
                    data : user
                })
            }
        })
    },
}
```

*Here my front code:*

**authenticationAPI.js:**

```
export const AuthenticationService = {
 getMe: () => {
    return axiosInstance
      .get(requests.getme, { credentials: "include" })
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  },
}
```

**config/requests.js:**

```
export const requests = {
    register : '/auth',
    login : '/auth/login',
    logout : '/auth/logout',
    getme : '/auth/me',
}
```

**authenticationSlice.js:**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { AuthenticationService } from "./authenticationAPI";

const initialState = {
  registerstatus: "",
  errormessage: "",
  userDetails: null,
};

//getme redux action
export const getMe = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/me",
  async () => {
    const response = AuthenticationService.getMe();
    return response;
  }
);

//creation du slice
const authenticationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authentication",
  initialState,

extraReducers: {

//getMe http request 3 cases
    [getMe.pending]: (state, action) => {

    },
    [getMe.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        console.log(action.payload);
        state.userDetails = action.payload.data.data
    },
    [getMe.rejected]: (state, action) => {

    },

export const { } = authenticationSlice.actions;
export const selectUserDetails = (state) => state.authentication.userDetails
export default authenticationSlice.reducer;
```

**views/posts/post.jsx:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getMe, selectUserDetails } from '../../features/authentication/authenticationSlice'
export default () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getMe())
    }, [])

    const userDetails = useSelector(selectUserDetails)
    

    return (
        <h5>{userDetails && userDetails.name}</h5>
        <hr />
        <h6>{userDetails && userDetails.email}</h6>
    )
}
```

The **email** and the **name** still do not render.

I tried runnig this code on browser, but i got theses two errors in devtools Console when i'm logged in (i can see the access_token in Application):

`Error: Request failed with status code 404`
`GET http://localhost:5000/auth/me 404 (Not Found)`

I really appreciate your help. Thank you all.

Comment: You should be sending POST requests to your endpoint, but you're sending a GET request, so you get a 404. In `authenticationAPI.js` change `return axiosInstance.get(...)` to `return axiosInstance.post(...)`.

Comment: Typo issue, thanks for discovering that!

Comment: problem solved, thanks again

Comment: No problem. It was kind of strange that you were sending a GET request for auth, so that quickly tracked the issue down ;)

Comment: Please may i kindly ask you if there any way to help me not getting in typo problems? i always been in such problems lately. i mean maybe there's a way that the compiler shows exactly and more informations about error so it will help me resolve any such kind of issues :)

Comment: Well, the easiest way to find a typo is probably by looking at the error. Here it says there was a 404 (so you have no controller on the server for such a request), then it says the request was GET. When I see GET I would probably think whether if I was sure the request was a GET or not. That will help you easily track down problems. The more you do this kind of thing, you'll have less typos. Best of luck to you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Express controller is handling only POST requests, so you get 404 when you try to hit that route with GET. The problem springs from `authenticationAPI.js`:

```js
return axiosInstance
  .get(...)
  // ...
```

Simply change it to

```js
return axiosInstance
  .post(...)
  // ...
```

That way you'll be able to actually hit the route with your request.

Comment: thanks :) this already solved my problem above